# Solving $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}\ge\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}\ge\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

This is an inequality I've been attempting. It is from a past olympiad (final stage of it, was called the national olympiad, and it was from Romania). But my method of solving was incomplete or plain wrong.

I've actually tried to bring the term from the right side to the left and to do the calculations but I might have miscalculated it ( although I've triple checked). I think a miscalculation is the actual reason but that seems like the lazy solution not the smart one.

Could someone please provide maybe a smarter solution to the problem that doesn't actually involve so many useless calculations? It could be a method that’s still lazy, but I really need an answer to the question. I've been contemplating on it for quite a while now, and I can't really get to actual solving as I am currently on holiday with some friends.

Sorry for so much context. I guess that's not really that relevant but an answer would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: First of all, welcome to MathSE! Well, we can help you if you edit your post and add the method that you tried, so that we can point your mistake, and you learn from it!

Comment: i took the term from the righthand side of the inequality and subtracted it from the term in left side and just did the calculations . I am looking for an alternate way

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, so share what you've done. If you're stuck, cross multiply and raise exponents, and observe that there are 2n terms on both sides.

Comment: well sorry if i am bad at this but this is literally my first post and i am not quite sure what the social procedure is so sorry . I had come to basically a reverse inequality . You would have n(n+1) ge than the factorial term and i am stuck at this point as i am not quite sure how to dissasemble the factorial part ( sorry i didn’t bother ot write the thing in actual mathematical term but i thought this was non that important )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$\iff n(n+1) \ge \sqrt[n]{(2n)!}\iff n(n+1) \ge \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^nk(2n+1-k)} \tag{1}$$

Applying the AM–GM inequality, we have
$$\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^nk(2n+1-k)} \le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nk(2n+1-k)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{3} n (1 + n) (2n+1) = (n+1)\frac{2n+1}{3}$$

As $\frac{2n+1}{3}\le n$ for all $n \ge 1$, we conclude that $(1)$ holds true for all $n \in \Bbb N^+$

Answer (score 0):

Here's another elementary way.

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}
\ge\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}
$
same as
$\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}
\le n(n+1)
$
or
$(2n)!
\le (n(n+1))^n
$.

Let
$r(n)
=\dfrac{(n(n+1))^n}{(2n)!}
$.

$r(1)
=\dfrac{2}{2}
=1
$,
$r(2)
=\dfrac{6^2}{24}
\gt 1
$,
$r(3)
=\dfrac{12^3}{6!}
=\dfrac{1728}{720}
\gt 1
$.

I will show that
$r(n)$
is increasing.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{r(n+1)}{r(n)}
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{((n+1)(n+2))^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}{\dfrac{(n(n+1))^n}{(2n)!}}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)n^n}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{2(2n+1)n^n}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)(1+2/n)^{n}}{2(2n+1)}\\
&\gt\dfrac{(1+2/n)^{n}}{4}
\qquad\text{since } n+1 > n+\frac12\\
\end{array}
$

From the first 3 terms
of the binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
(1+2/n)^n
&\gt 1+n(2/n)+n(n-1)(2/n)^2/2\\
&= 1+2+2(n-1)/n\\
&=5-2/n\\
&\gt 4
\qquad\text{for } n > 2\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$r(n+1) > r(n)$
for $n \gt 2$
so
$r(n) > 1$
for all $n$.